# jquery error when trying to parse object

Tags: jquery, json

I'm fetching some data from a server, and i have them returned in json as objects.

My ajax request is the following:

```
$.ajax({
 url: Url,
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (result) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(result)
            $(".result").text(obj);
           }
})
```

If i try to use `JSON.parse(result)`, it returns an error: `Unexpected token o` but on my network tab has the result element correct:

```
{service: "29”,…}
{service: “33",…}
{service: “45”,…}
{service: “70",…}
```

If i **don't** use `JSON.parse(result)`, what i have printed is the following:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

what am i doing wrong?
Thanks

**EDIT:**

if i use this code here:

```
$.ajax({
   url: Url,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (result) {
                    console.log (result)
                    $(".result").text(result.service);
                    console.debug (result.service);
                }
            })
```

The first console has the following results:

```
0: Object
 service: "29"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
 service: "29"
__proto__: Object
```

but nothing is printed in the div, and the second console is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you're using `dataType:"json"` you don't need to parse the json object, it is by default parsed and you can use it as an object.

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback)

From [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: so i need to print something like result.service?

Comment: that is exactly what you should do

Comment: then you're not defining your json in the back-end correctly

Comment: ok i think is because i need a loop to check every object.
i have it working now.
thanks for your reply

Comment: glad you got it figured out ;)